# How to programmatically achieve layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf in constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to add a text view to the right end of the parent with the below code. But it is not working as expected.

```
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    TextView mValue1 = new TextView(getContext());
    mValue1.setText("Value 1");
    mValue1.setId(R.id.rightLabel1);
    addView(mValue1);
    constraintSet.clone(this);
    constraintSet.connect(mValue1.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, this.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP);
    constraintSet.connect(mValue1.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, this.getId(), ConstraintSet.END);
    constraintSet.applyTo(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that I did not set the id of root constraint layout. If I simply set the id, it works. Or 

Changing

```
    constraintSet.connect(mValue1.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, this.getId(), ConstraintSet.END);
```

to

```
    constraintSet.connect(mValue1.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END);
```

solves the issue.